# Keras constraint for whole layer unit norm

Tags: keras, neural-network, constraints, keras-layer

https://keras.io/constraints/

It seems the built-in constraints in Keras will constrain each node in the layer individually. What I need is to constrain the weights in a dense layer to be non negative (which I see in the docs) but also for the whole layer to have unit norm. So that’s the sum of all the weights in the layer should be 1. Is there a way to do this that I’m not seeing in the docs?

Comment: There isn't something ready I think, but there is `l2_normalize(...)` in keras backend so you can take inspiration from it and write your own `l1_normalize(...)`.

Comment: @marcoromelli Yes i see that function. So, just assuming I use `l2_normalize`, do you know how I would use that as a constraint on the weights of a dense layer?

Comment: In the question you talked about the *activations* of a dense layer. Constraining the weights is a different story. Have you tried using `keras.constraints.UnitNorm(axis=[0,1])` as `kernel_constraint ` of the Dense layer?

Comment: @marcoromelli Sorry the wording should be changed, it is the weights I want to constrain. I saw the UnitNorm, but it seems from the source that this is enforcing a unit L2 norm, so it is almost what I need, but I need the L1 norm. I just found here seems to be a general way to apply your own constraints: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8196